# How to select value from a list based on value in a column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column called **storage** with a drop-down list. The cells in the storage column have a data validation where they must be selected from the list. The list is the range hiddenSheet!$A$3:$I$3.

I have a column (Z) which has the values that need to go in for each field, but they are in string and I don't know how to tell Excel to select the equivalent value from the list.

Here is the Z column.

[image: Column Z with the values to select from list]

I simply want to select the value in column Z and place it in the cell in the storage column for each cell **without violating the data validation**. This is because this needs to be imported into an SQL database.

Comment: What is the source of the data in column Z?  If it is operator entered, then why not do the data validation there?  If it is already populated and may sometimes not match your list, then it would probably work better to flag non-matches for operator intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH([STORAGE_LOC_CD],hiddenSheet!$A$3:$I$3,0))=FALSE,[STORAGE_LOC_CD],"No Match")
```

You would need to add "No Match" to the data validation list in your hidden sheet, then maybe you can deal with the value "No Match" in a way that doesn't mess up your data.

Comment: still got the error, storage must be selected from drop-down list!!